# Django order by multiple filtered foreign key values

Tags: python, django

I am attempting to sort by multiple values on related fields, filtered by a key, but running the second `order_by` is ordering by the *first* filter, not the most recent.

```
class Product(Model):
    name = CharField()


class ProductAttribute(Model):
    product = ForeignKey(Product)
    key = CharField()
    value = FloatField()


# This line sorts products as expected over the `ProductAttribute`s with a key of 'score'
products = Product.objects.filter(productattribute_set__key='score')\
                          .order_by('productattribute_set__value')

# This line sorts products as expected over the `ProductAttribute`s with a key of 'rating'
products = Product.objects.filter(productattribute_set__key='rating')\
                          .order_by('productattribute_set__value')

# This line sorts products based on score only, not on rating, then score (or vise versa)
products = Product.objects.filter(productattribute_set__key='score')\
                          .order_by('productattribute_set__value')\
                          .filter(productattribute_set__key='rating')\
                          .order_by('productattribute_set__value')
```

Is there a way to order by `score`'s value, and then `rating`'s value?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the kind of answer you're looking for, but I would suggest adding rating and score into your Product table as foreign keys to the product attribute as opposed to the other way around. To me, this makes more sense as a model.

```
class Product(Model):
    name = CharField()
    score = ForeignKey(ProductAttribute)
    rating = ForeignKey(ProductAttribute)


class ProductAttribute(Model):
    key = CharField()
    value = FloatField()
```

This you can then order easily using:

```
order_by(score__value, rating__value)
```

The other way I think creates too much unnecessary work, especially if you don't have too many additional product attributes.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't really an option. A `Product` can have 30+ different `ProductAttribute`s, none of which are guaranteed to exist. In our case `Product` is the parent, and `ProductAttribute` is the child.

Comment: Your question is not very clear @TorelTwiddler this seems a legit answer based on my understanding of your question

Comment: @e4c5 I'm not sure how I can make it more clear. This isn't an acceptable answer because I would need to make a very significant number of changes (weeks of work) to make this change. I don't feel that saying "change your premise" is a good answer to a problem.